# Android: Creating a custom alert dialog inside a dynamic onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Not sure how well that title describes what I am hoping to do but here goes. Basically I have an app that pragmatically creates a list of buttons which when clicked then return a description.

I created the following class

```
public class DynamicOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
{

    String description;
    public DynamicOnClickListener(String adesc) {
        //sets the description attribute at instantiation
         this.description = adesc;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //on button click returns dialog box with description in it
        Log.v("DynamicOnClickListener","1");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
        builder.setMessage(description);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                   {
                       dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();   
        alert.show();
    }

 }
```

This works perfectly as is, however I would very much like to jazz up the dialog box somewhat. I have been looking at some examples online and according to the android docs they suggest defining a custom xml layout and using LayourInflator set the custom xml as the view for the dialog. (Well thats how I understood it anyway, probably wrongly right enough)

Although the docs example is slightly different from mine, according to their example I should add the following lines

```
// Get the layout inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

// Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
// Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
```

However when I add this to my class, resulting in the following I get an error on getActivity()

```
public class DynamicOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
{

    String description;
    public DynamicOnClickListener(String adesc) {
        //sets the description attribute at instantiation
         this.description = adesc;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //on button click returns dialog box with program description in it
        Log.v("DynamicOnClickListener","1");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());

        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.description_dialog, null));


        builder.setMessage(description);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                   {
                       dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();   
        alert.show();
    }

 }
```

Comment: v.getContext() instead of getActivity

Comment: I tried that but that then gives me an error on getLayoutInflator();

Comment: DynamicOnClickListener where this class is declared /

Comment: It is contained within its own file and instantiated within a method of the main activity

Comment: see the answer posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final Context mContext = v.getContext()
inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.description_dialog, null));
```

Try this.

Answer (score 3):

I did the dialogue box with an EditText to enter email and a button to send the data and to cancel it..
This dialogue box is shown by making the background dim.  And displaying it on top of the current activity.

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
               LinearLayout popUp = new LinearLayout(this);
               popUp.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
               popUp.setOrientation(1);

                EditText t1 = new  EditText(this);
                t1.setHint("Enter Your Email ID ");
                t1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                t1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);          

                LinearLayout btnLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                btnLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                btnLayout.setOrientation(0);
                btnLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                Button send = new  Button(this);
                send.setText("Send");
                send.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                Button cancel = new  Button(this);
                cancel.setText("Cancel");
                cancel.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                btnLayout.addView(send);
                btnLayout.addView(cancel);
                popUp.addView(t1);
                popUp.addView(btnLayout);

                dialog.setContentView(popUp);
              cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
                dialog.show();
```

Comment: Wow, its working. Tried for two days all the examples with Inflator.  This is  does exactly what i want. I am building a cordova plugin and i don't want to include an extra xml for the layout.

Answer (score 1):

According to CoderDecoder and kleopatra's answers here is the updated version with a shape.

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.shape_client_textview_background_color));
    shape.setStroke(10, getResources().getColor(R.color.shape_client_textview_border_color));
    shape.setCornerRadius(50);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LinearLayout popUp = new LinearLayout(this);
   // popUp.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    layoutParams.setMargins(20,20,20,20);
    popUp.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    popUp.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    popUp.setBackground(shape);
    popUp.setPadding(20,20,20,20);

    EditText t1 = new EditText(this);
    t1.setHint("Enter Your Email ID ");
    t1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    t1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);

    LinearLayout btnLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
 //   btnLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    btnLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    btnLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    Button send = new Button(this);
    send.setText("Send");
    send.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    Button cancel = new Button(this);
    cancel.setText("Cancel");
    cancel.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    btnLayout.addView(send);
    btnLayout.addView(cancel);
    popUp.addView(t1);
    popUp.addView(btnLayout);

    dialog.setContentView(popUp);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```

Here is the result:

[image: Dynamic dialog with a shape]